# Displaying 21 spinners to select body parts

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I just wanted to ask how can I make my code a bit shorter. As of now, I have way too much code in the class. The program should display about twenty one spinners. I know it's a lot, but in this layout, users have to create their own training plan for 3 training days. In every training day, user has to select up to three body parts (one body part - 3 spinners with exercises, it should look like that)

```
Monday:

Chest: -first exercise (spinner) -second exercise (spinner) -third exercise (spinner)

Triceps -first exercise (spinner) -second exercise (spinner) -third exercise (spinner) etc..
```

I've already filled spinners with exercises from database, but I want to make this class shorter because for filling my spinners (just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) I've written about 2400 lines of code where about 2000 it's just copied method, with changed adapter etc. Did can i make it shorter? Here's first method

```
public void setMondayFirstBodyPart_1() {

    switch (mondayFirstBodyPartFirstExerciseString) {
        case "shoulders": {
            List<String> data = db.getShouldersData();
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            mondayFirstBodyPartFirstExercise.setAdapter(adapter);
            mondayFirstBodyPartExerciseTV.setText("Shoulders");
            break;
        }
        case "chest": {
            List<String> data = db.getChestData();
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            mondayFirstBodyPartFirstExercise.setAdapter(adapter);
            mondayFirstBodyPartExerciseTV.setText("Chest");
            break;
        }
        case "back": {
            List<String> data = db.getBackData();
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            mondayFirstBodyPartFirstExercise.setAdapter(adapter);
            mondayFirstBodyPartExerciseTV.setText("Back");
            break;
        }
        case "biceps": {
            List<String> data = db.getBicepsData();
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            mondayFirstBodyPartFirstExercise.setAdapter(adapter);
            mondayFirstBodyPartExerciseTV.setText("Biceps");
            break;
        }
        case "triceps": {
            List<String> data = db.getTricepsData();
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            mondayFirstBodyPartFirstExercise.setAdapter(adapter);
            mondayFirstBodyPartExerciseTV.setText("Triceps");
            break;
        }
        case "forearm": {
            List<String> data = db.getForearmData();
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            mondayFirstBodyPartFirstExercise.setAdapter(adapter);
            mondayFirstBodyPartExerciseTV.setText("Forearm");
            break;
        }
        case "stomach": {
            List<String> data = db.getAbsData();
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            mondayFirstBodyPartFirstExercise.setAdapter(adapter);
            mondayFirstBodyPartExerciseTV.setText("Stomach");
            break;
        }
        case "legs": {
            List<String> data = db.getLegsData();
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            mondayFirstBodyPartFirstExercise.setAdapter(adapter);
            mondayFirstBodyPartExerciseTV.setText("Legs");
            break;
        }
        case "calf": {
            List<String> data = db.getCalfData();
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            mondayFirstBodyPartFirstExercise.setAdapter(adapter);
            mondayFirstBodyPartExerciseTV.setText("Calf");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. I suggest that you show more context, so that we can advise you properly. For example, what does the `db` code look like? See [ask].

Comment: Every case statement is the same except the setText parameter. So just extract the whole duplicated case statement in new method with just one parameter.

Comment: @Ankit Soni - the `List<String> data` also gets different values depending on the case.

Comment: @0X0nosugar, you are right, my bad. Two parameters then, the db data list and text value.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at one of the `case` blocks:

```
case "shoulders": {
    List<String> data = db.getShouldersData();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mondayFirstBodyPartFirstExercise.setAdapter(adapter);
    mondayFirstBodyPartExerciseTV.setText("Shoulders");
    break;
}
```

The only lines which depend directly on the selected body part are

```
List<String> data = db.getShouldersData();
```

and

```
mondayFirstBodyPartExerciseTV.setText("Shoulders");
```

So let's suppose you have a method `findDataForBodyPart(String bodyPart)` which will make the database call and return the data list (or an empty list if there is no data to be found). In addition to that, you need another method `getNameOfBodyPart(String)` which will take a `String` (e.g. "shoulders") and return the desired `TextView` text (e.g. "Shoulders").

Then you can abbreviate your code as follows:

```
public void setMondayFirstBodyPart_1() {
    List<String> data = findDataForBodyPart(mondayFirstBodyPartFirstExerciseString);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mondayFirstBodyPartFirstExercise.setAdapter(adapter);
    mondayFirstBodyPartExerciseTV.setText(getNameOfBodyPart(mondayFirstBodyPartFirstExerciseString));
 }
```

You can avoid even more repetitions (this time of whole methods) if you pass the value of *mondayFirstBodyPartFirstExerciseString* as parameter into the method, together with the corresponding `Spinner` and `TextView`:

```
public void setExerciseFor(String bodyPartString, Spinner exerciseSpinner, TextView exerciseTextView) {
    List<String> data = findDataForBodyPart(bodyPartString);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    exerciseSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    exerciseTextView.setText(getNameOfBodyPart(bodyPartString));
 }
```

Please note that in order to suggest further improvements, we'd need to see more of your code.

Comment: When adding additional information you should [edit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/207391/edit) your answer  instead of adding a comment. I have added that information to your post. Learn more about comments including when to comment and when not to in [the Help Center page about Comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of what type `mondayFirstBodyPartFirstExercise` currently is but maybe you could use polymorphism and add the behavior there. This would would put database logic into your entities though. ([Active Record pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern))

```
public void setMondayFirstBodyPart_1() {
    List<String> data = mondayFirstBodyPartFirstExercise.getData();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mondayFirstBodyPartFirstExercise.setAdapter(adapter);
    mondayFirstBodyPartExerciseTV.setText(mondayFirstBodyPartFirstExercise.getBodyPartName());
 }
```